# Right way to store data on an angular mobile app

Tags: angularjs, mobile

I'm working on an AngularJS based mobile app using Cordova and required to persist data locally.

I see Cordova offers an API to local storage via window.localStorage, but I have a bunch of unclear questions:

- Is the Cordova window.localStorage the same as HTML5 localStorage and, if so, is subject to the same limitation of the HTML5 browser (aprox 5Mb space?
- Is this storage flushed or cleared at some time (i.e. on mobile low space) or is it persistent guarantied?
- In addition, is IndexedDB subject to space limits too like localStorage?

Thanks.

Comment: The localStorage limit is vendor specific.

Comment: More than space I'm worried about the persistence of data, is the localStorage area flushed and some time? Thanks

Comment: Did my answer clear everything up?

Comment: I think so. I'm finally using WebSQL to persist my mobile app data. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Cordova docs

`localStorage, Provides access to the W3C's Web Storage interface`.

So `window.localStorage` === `HTML5 localStorage`.

The w3c Web sotrage interface says 
`This specification defines an API for persistent data storage of key-value pair data in Web clients.`

So yes, it should be persistent (and not flushed away after x time), but you have to check up which each vendor you want to support, how they handle low-memory, limits, flushing (if any)..

IndexedDB space limit is also vendor specific, but it is never unlimited (then it would be pretty easy to fill your memory .. )